# Prevent file locking on Windows

Tags: file-permissions

I'm searching for a way to prevent locking a certain file.

**Background:**

- Microsoft DNS writes logs to a certain file and until a certain file size which can be set.
- When the file size is reached, Microsoft DNS deletes/clears (actually not sure if deleted or cleared) the file and starts from beginning.
- The Folder in which the log is stored in is mounted as Network share on a SUSE SLES 11 SP4 System. On this System, a Software is reading the file to parse it's log entries and send it to another system.
- **If this Software is running, Microsoft DNS is not able to delete/clear the file to start writing from beginning. The file just disappears and Microsoft DNS stops logging**
- **The share is mounted ro and the used user just has ro permissions.**
- I guess this is because of some Kind of file lock, set by the Software, even if just ro permissions are in place.

**Question:**

- Is there a way to prevent applications locking a file? Similar to set read/write permission?

Thank you in advance!